# How to prove let $f(x)=(x^2 +x)^n, f^{(n)} (x) $ has $n$ roots

Tags: calculus

let $f(x)=(x^2 +x)^n$, $f^{(n)} (x) $ has $n$ roots in$[0,1]$.

By mathmatical induction?

Comment: I assumed you mean $f^{(n)}$, the $n$-th derivative of $f$, and edited accordingly.

Comment: @Arthur Thank you so much!

Comment: Is the $n$ in $f$ the same as the $n$ in the derivatives? i.e. let $f_n=(x^2+x)^n$ and you want to see that the $n$-th derivative of $f_n$ has exactly $n$ (different?) roots in $[0,1]$? In this case you get that $f_1'(x)=2x+1$ which has no roots in $[0,1]$ and not one.

Comment: @AngeloRendina maximum different n roots

Comment: @user366725 what are you trying to show then? That your $f_n $ has at most $n $ roots or that it **has** $n$ roots

Comment: @user366725 $f$ is a polynomial of degree $2n$. So $f^{(n)}$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, it has at most $n$ roots